# Quais são as ferramentas disponíveis para cobertura de código em .NET em Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tdd

Tenho desenvolvido sistemas utilizando TDD em .NET. Recentemente, a empresa que trabalho, comprou a versão do Visual Studio 2013 Pro e, nesta versão não temos a ferramenta de cobertura de código (code coverage), somente a partir da versão Premium ([visual studio compare versions](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx)) a cobertura de código está disponível.

Dessa forma, quais as opções que tenho?

Quais as ferramentas opensource (free) para cobertura de código, são equivalentes a ferramenta do visual studio versão Premium em diante?

O que gosto muito é a experiência de estar tudo integrado ao visual studio, porém, se existir alguma ferramenta, mesmo que não esteja totalmente integrada, mas que ofereça uma boa experiência e desempenho, não me importo com a integração.

Comment: [Nesta questão tem um resumão sobre várias ferramentas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net) (em inglês)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse link do Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net) levou a conclusão que não existem muitos aplicativos free.

O único free seria o OpenCover https://github.com/sawilde/opencover